# UITabBar items title position issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

[image: tab bar]

I cannot solve this issue, related to the position of the title of every single tab bar item in a `UITabBar`. I tried with this:

```swift
extension UITabBar {
    override open var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)
        }
        return super.traitCollection
    }
}
```

With no success. How can I solve this misalignment?

Comment: For iPad, please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217563/uitabbarappearance-does-not-work-on-ios15-ipad-title-color

Answer (score 4):

Check if this is worked, change values in `UIOffset` per what position you want.

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    
    // set padding between tabbar item title and image
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
    
    self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
} else {
    // set padding between tabbar item title and image
    UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4)
}
```

Comment: I was very hopeful. But it didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions? @ChuckZHB